# how to append html to the bottom of a list in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to append a loading div below the list, like how the listpaging does it. (I am not using listpaging for other reasons). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Then why don't your look at the ListPaging.js to see how it does it ?

Comment: ListPaging binds an event to store load. And I could not exactly figure it out.

Comment: Why did this get down voted?

Answer (score 1):

Set your Layout of the Container to 'vbox' and add a container below your list with your html.

**Example:**

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.MyView", {
    extend : "Ext.Container",
    config : {
        layout : 'vbox',
        fullscreen : true,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'list',
            itemTpl : '{name}',
            store : 'MyStore',
            layout : 'fit',
            flex : 1                    
        }, {
            height : 50,
            xtype : 'container',
            html : "HELLO WORLD"
        }]        
    }
});
```

Sencha Fiddle Example: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#GJqsv